# nginx invalid URL prefix in "" with map

Tags: nginx, proxy

`proxy_pass` worked if I keep `default http://127.0.0.1:9200` uncomment,
 but with the below code map to `~^/kibana-dev` the `proxy_pass` doesn't worked and I get 500 if I go to `http://my.domain.com/kibana-dev`

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}


http {

    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    map $request_uri $target {
        #default http://127.0.0.1:9200;
        ~^/kibana-dev http://127.0.0.1:9200;
        ~^/kibana-test http://127.0.0.1:9100;
    }

    server {

        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

        if ( $request_uri ~* ^/kibana-test ) {
        return 301 http://my.domain.com/_plugin/kibana;
        }

        if ( $request_uri ~* ^/kibana-dev ) {
        return 301 http://my.domain.com/_plugin/kibana;
        }

        location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP 1.2.3.4;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Connect "Keep-Alive";
        proxy_set_header Proxy-Connection "Keep-Alive";
        proxy_set_header Authorization "";
        proxy_pass $target;
        }

    }
}
```

I also tried :

```
map $uri $target {
        /kibana-dev http://127.0.0.1:9200;
    }
```

Any idea why ?
Thanks

Comment: Your `if` blocks change the URI to `/_plugin/kibana` before the `map` is consulted. So only the `default` case will be taken.

Comment: thanks, I thought that server configuration come after the http/map

Comment: @RichardSmith so it goes like this -> if block, map block, location ?

Comment: I see that map is not allowed under server

Comment: Your configuration file is syntactically correct already. It just make no sense.

Comment: I am not sure I understand, I need to use the root location because I have some complex proxy nodejs apps, is there a way to pass var from the if block to the map block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your configuration file does not make sense.

If you present the URI `http://my.domain.com/kibana-dev`, the `server` block will execute:

```
return 301 http://my.domain.com/_plugin/kibana;
```

This causes the URI to be represented as `/_plugin/kibana`. The new URI is processed by the `location /` block and executes:

```
proxy_pass $target;
```

At this point, the `map` is consulted to determine the value of `$target` which is the `default` value as `/_plugin/kibana` does not match any of the other values.

Comment: its works because the proxy apps inside the machines, what I wanted to do if there is `/kibana-dev` it will set a value to `$target`, later on I will use it in proxy pass.

Comment: thanks, do you know if there is a way to run the map before the server block ?

Comment: The server is state-less, so once you `return`, the transaction has finished. `nginx` cannot know what the original URI was. Why do you rewrite the URI to `/_plugin/kibana`? Does the browser need to know, or is this just to change the URI for the upstream service?

Comment: sorry for my late reply, I will update tomorrow my question, and explain you in details why I needed to to make this workaround instead of different locations, /example1 /example2. thank you.

Comment: I post new question, can you please help ?
link here:
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41955510/nginx-location-directive-not-working-with-nodejs-proxy-apps),
thanks